# Replace dead keys of default US keyboard layout on Lion?

Tags: macos, keyboard, customization, internationalization

I've been trying to create a new keyboard layout using Ukelele on Lion. I want to replace some dead keys combination like `option+e` to `option+'`.

Ukelele seems to be the right tool for it. Problem is, since Lion, it doesn't support the "New from Current Input Source" option, which means I can't seem to simply edit the "US" layout to replace the dead keys I want.

Is there an already working keylayout that works on Lion and replaces the option+letter combinations with option+accent?

Is there another solution for this problem?

Where can I find the original Lion keylayouts? I've tried using old keylayouts (or automatically generated ones), but then a lot of subtle things breaking (like text selection on textmate).

Comment: What do you mean by old keylayouts? Ukelele's disk image comes with some `.keylayouts`. (Their modification dates seem to be in 2008, but the default keyboard layouts in Lion shouldn't be that different.)

Comment: When I try to use them without any modifications some things break, for instance mac+A on textmate stops selecting the whole text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New version of Ukelele supports "New from Current Input Source" on Lion. Managed to create a keylayout that solves my problem. Downoad it here: [US AltGr.keylayout](https://gist.github.com/1304395)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to emulate the US International layout found on PC's, where you type the accent mark and then the base letter, you can use the US International - PC layout provided with Lion.

I've made a lot of layouts with Ukelele and I think there are always some of those subtle things that can break, luckily none that matter for me.  You might write the author of the app about your particular problems.

There is no way to access the Lion system layouts for modification as far as I know.

Comment: I don't want to have dead keys, i.e., I don't want to press `'` and `e` for `é`. I want to press `option+'` and `e`. What I dislike on the mac is which key is mapped to each accent.